# Add New Schema/Subject to Schema Registry in Kafka Avro file format

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to run schema to a schema registry by explicit curl command.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"  --data '{"schema" : {"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}'  http://localhost:8081/subjects/avro-test/versions/
```

I am getting the below error 
**{"error_code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error"}**

Note : I am able to access the data from the existing subject but getting the same error while pushing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema needs to be string escaped

For example, starting out

```
POST -d'{"schema": {\"type\":\"record\"
```

If you can, then installing `jq` tool and create an AVSC file instead, that would help - [see my comment here](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/789#issuecomment-385064491)

Comment: Thank you!! I have got it corrected but still getting the same error..Is there any way to create a new folder in subjects before pushing the schema?

Comment: What do you mean by folder? There is no concept of folders in schema registry

Comment: I mean the subject- avro-test in the schema registry url : http://localhost:8081/subjects/avro-test/versions
How do we create it of it is not available already?it is not creating automatically when I try to post the schema

Comment: It's not created because you're getting errors. And you're getting errors because the Avro schema needs to be a string value for a `"schema"` JSON key... In any case, I don't understand why you need to do this manually. If you configure a producer AvroSerializer, then it'll post the schema for you for the topic name you're producing into

Comment: I have made the changes suggested by you..by including schema json key...
Again I am getting error because the subject is not available..can we create a subject by using a curl command?or should i write a avro serializer for creating a subject and a schema for a topic..

Comment: Now the new schema looks like this '{"schema": "{\"type\": \"string\"}"}' but I am getting **{"error_code":50002,"message":"Register operation timed out"}**